# How to add several parameters in SIGNAL SET MESSAGE_TEXT?

Tags: mysql

Using mysql 8 I call signal and I want in message text concat several errors, but I got error :

> 000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the  right syntax to use
> near '('Invalid parameter provided : ',' at line 44.

with code :

```
    IF(cond) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = concat('Invalid parameter provided : ', addParamId, ' and ', paramId );

    END IF;
```

Which syntax is valid here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html)

> Valid *simple_value_specification* designators can be specified using stored procedure or function parameters, stored program local variables declared with `DECLARE`, user-defined variables, system variables, or literals.

So you can't use an expression there, only a literal or variable. You should assign the concatenation to a variable and then use that.

```
DECLARE error_msg VARCHAR(100);
.
.
.
    IF(cond) THEN
        SET error_msg = concat('Invalid parameter provided : ', addParamId, ' and ', paramId );
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = error_msg;
    END IF;
```

Comment: I got error : [HY000][1193] Unknown system variable 'error_msg'.   I suppose that I have to use @error_msg var or with DECLARE. Which way is preferable in this case ?

Comment: Declared variables are generally preferable, since they're local to the procedure. I'm not sure why you're getting that error when I show how to use `DECLARE`.